# Check From Email address when using email template in Salesforce without using org-wide address

Tags: apex, email, email-template, user

Good Day Everyone,

I have created an email template in salesforce. When I use it to send an email via apex, It uses my current email as from address. Now what I did is that I defreeze my current user that creates the said email template. My question is that, what will happen if I login to another user and use the email template ? What will be the from address it will use ? In short, my question is that what is the correct way to determine the from address when sending and email in salesforce.

Note: I did not set-up the org-wide address for this scenario.

Please help. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm) is pretty clear on this

> The email address of the user calling the sendEmail method is inserted
>   in the From Address field of the email header. All email that is
>   returned, bounced, or received out-of-office replies goes to the user
>   calling the method.

Hence, the running user of the apex class that sends the email will be the 'from' email address.

If you want emails to go out from a consistent email address, use an org-wide email address using the method `setOrgWideEmailAddressId(emailAddressId)`